# lxml -- how to isolate element from children

Tags: python, html, xml, html-parsing, lxml

Using lxml, I'd like to be able to get an HTML  element and turn it into a string, excluding its children.  How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, instead of downvoting, it'd be much more helpful if you could just answer the question.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote, but I think I know the reason - there is no example input and output, hence it is too broad. Please improve your question.

Comment: It's pretty unambiguous.  Imagine an HtmlElement.  Now imagine it without its children.  *boom*

Comment: Don't get me wrong (and no offense) - if you want someone to help you, help that someone to help you by making an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `remove` method to remove the children:

```
import lxml.html as LH

code = '''<a foo="bar">some text<b></b> here <c><d>Hi</d></c> and here</a>'''

root = LH.fromstring(code)
print(root.text_content())
# some text here Hi and here

for elt in root:
    root.remove(elt)

print(LH.tostring(root))
```

yields

```
<a foo="bar">some text</a>
```

Note, however, that not all text returned by `text_content` is preserved after
you remove the children.

Comment: assuming deep copying the original element, this is what i'm looking for